# INSERT SELECT with another value added

Tags: php, multiple-insert

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include '_includes/db.php';

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `en_stud` (en_subj, en_desc, en_code) 
     SELECT subj_code, subj_name, subj_deg FROM `subjects` WHERE subj_deg='PREP'"); 

            }

?>
</form>
```

Hi, Ok, so i used the INSERT SELECT for this, in order to insert all regular subjects for prep inside the database, but what if i wanted to add something. Like

Adding

Input Box and another value separated into the select table command, how would i be able to add it there?

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="f" value="1"
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {      
        include '_includes/db.php';

            $f = "$_POST['f']";

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `en_stud` (en_fname, en_subj, en_desc, en_code) 
         SELECT subj_code, subj_name, subj_deg FROM `subjects` WHERE subj_deg='PREP'"); 

                }


    ?>
    </form>
```

As you can see the "en_fname" doesn't have any corresponding values, does this have any corresponding code to make it work?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {      
    include '_includes/db.php';

        $f = "$_POST['f']";

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `en_stud` (en_fname, en_subj, en_desc, en_code) VALUES ('$f')
     SELECT subj_code, subj_name, subj_deg FROM `subjects` WHERE subj_deg='PREP'"); 

            }


?>
</form>
```

Comment: Sanitize your input. Use, -at least- `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I will sir, this is just a test file. I'll be doing the same if it's finished. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `en_stud` (en_fname, en_subj, en_desc, en_code) 
     SELECT '$f', subj_code, subj_name, subj_deg FROM `subjects` WHERE subj_deg='PREP'");
```

Basically you have to put all values in `SELECT` list. So instead of trying to join own values with select values, just put additional values in select list. They are constant, so it's like

```
Select 1,2,'three', some_field FROM some_table
```

Comment: be sure to write some description on what you did. SO demands quality answers